# ProtoBuf-net Deserialize does not work

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

code is here:

```
        var responseMsg = new ResponseMessage()
        {
            code = ErrorCode.OK,
            type = MsgType.LOGIN,
            responseStr = "this is local server"
        };
        var serverStream = new MemoryStream();
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(serverStream, responseMsg);
        Console.WriteLine($"responseMsg {responseMsg?.responseStr ?? "failed"}\n");

        var response =ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<ResponseMessage>(serverStream);
        Console.WriteLine($"response {response?.responseStr ?? "failed"}\n");
```

result is

```
responseMsg this is local server

response
```

ProtoBuf-net can not Deserialize what it Serialized. it's really a strange thing

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewind the stream to the beginning by resetting its [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx) before you can read from it:

```
serverStream.Position = 0;
var response = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<ResponseMessage>(serverStream);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XEFzcW).