# C# DataContractSerializer exception when Deserializing 'The data at the root level is invalid'

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

**[SOLVED]**
**There was an error deserializing the object of type 'Message'. The data at the root level is invalid**

I have the following code for Serializing/Deserializing

```
    public static byte[] Serialize(object Object)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(Object.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, Object);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static Type Deserialize<Type>(byte[] SerializedData)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(SerializedData))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Type));
            return (Type)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

This is the class I'm serializing

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class Message
{
    public string MessageType = string.Empty;
    public string MessageData = string.Empty;
}
```

Here is how it is used

```
    void Send(string MessageType, string Data)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.MessageType = MessageType;
        message.MessageData = Data;
        byte[] byteData = Serializer.Serialize(message); // SERIALIZE

        // Send the data
        stream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    }

    Message Receive()
    {
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Message message = Serializer.Deserialize(bytes); // DESERIALIZE
        return message;
    }
```

I have tried several different things I have found on google from similar issues, but I cannot fix the issue.  Is there something wrong with the way I'm serializing?

Comment: 1) How is the `stream` member defined?  Is it the same `Stream` instance in both `Send()` and `Receive()`?  If so, did you remember to rewind the stream as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40296891/3744182).  2)  Your `Message` type has no [data member attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) so none of its properties will get serialized.

Comment: The stream is a NetworkStream and is a separate instance, one on the server and one on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

There were two issues. The first issue is [DataContractAttribute] need to be [Serializable]

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public string MessageType = string.Empty;
    public string MessageData = string.Empty;
}
```

Second is related to something not visible in the code above.
The 'bytes' array was initialized to a size greater than the data received, causing the Deserializer to not work properly.

I just created a new data array with the appropriate size to pass to the Deserializer

```
Message Receive()
{
    int messageLength = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    byte[] data = new byte[messageLength];
    Array.Copy(bytes, data, messageLength);

    Message message = Serializer.Deserialize(data); // DESERIALIZE
    return message;
}
```